# How to access a file on a Linux VM from VMware host?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I know there are some similar questions.  However, twist with this one is that I am locked out of the vm.  I don't have the root password for the VM.  However, I still want to get a file off of the VM.  Since I am locked out, I can't use normal methods to get the file, setting up a share, ftp, etc.

In the old days, you could just hook a harddrive up to another computer and read the files from it.  I am trying to do the same thing, but with a VM.

I have access to the VMware host, and the VM can be stopped or started, but I don't have the actual password for the VM OS.  Note, the VM OS is redhat linux.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you try to use `sudo`?

Comment: so shutdown the VM, attach the disk to another linux VM as an additional disk, and try to access it that way. is there any problem you are having with that process?

Comment: Add an ISO image of some live Linux system to the VM and boot from the virtual CD/DVD. For example, you could use an Ubuntu installation media and choose to *try* Ubuntu.

Comment: @FrankThomas That is what I suggested to my admin.  He was able to figure out the lost password, though.

Comment: For future people, this link might be helpful.  https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-896E61F5-0865-4D3B-975E-DE476AFC7168.html.  It basically explains how to do what @FrankThomas said.